# In Hindu mythology why all eight immortals are male?

Tags: scripture, immortality, chiranjivi

According to Hindu mythology, Why we consider all immortals count only 8 with no female and few other characters not included? Did any Hindu scriptures mentioned the reasons, why?

I found an [Article](http://devdutt.com/articles/indian-mythology/mahabharata/the-immortals.html), it mention few other characters who are immortal in Hindu mythology but who do not make it to the list. For example, Muchukunda, the son of Mandhata, who slept so long in a cave after a war, that when he opened his eyes, his first glance was so fiery that it set aflame the man who had rudely interrupted his sleep. There is Kalyavana, destroyer of Mathura, enemy of Krishna. Or Jambavan, the bear who served in Ram’s army and helped in the rescue of Sita. Or Banasura, the father of Usha, who was defeated by Krishna, but blessed by Shiva.

If they are immortals, why we are not consider them as an immortals?

Comment: There are many immortals who didn't make to the list.It is same as Vishnu's Dashavatars. Banasura was not an immortal. In Mahabharata and Shiva Purana, it is said that [he was killed by Skanda](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22047/5212). He is not a chiranjeevi. Is Kalayavana a chiranjivi? Many lived for mahayugas. That  doesn't make them chiranjivis.

Comment: Good question! There seem to be no women in the list of immortals whether they are included in this list of 8 or not.

Comment: There aren't many female heros in Hinduism. Kalidevi could be regarded as somewhat of a female hero. I think this is due to the fact that women tend to take a role of a caregiver/parent in the scriptures.

Comment: I hope they exist, somehow, but maybe are just not included in the well known list ? Is a good question 